# Why a mesh is begin squishes connected on a path with the curve modifier?

Tags: path

[image]

This has never happened before, where am I going wrong, so weird.

Comment: it's hard to understand your problem, are you talking about the circuit or about the animation? As Arthur said, maybe share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I fixed it brother, thanks for the response, but that did not work out for me in the end.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9hBQFIf_OQ
I saw this video on youtube, I really like how it works, so now I am learning how to use the constraints and rigging. If you could share something that would help me with it, it'll be great.

Answer (score 0):

As always with the curve modifier there is a lot that can go wrong lol, but I'd say you haven't applied the scale of your curve.

Comment: I have brother, I applied it, on the mesh and curve. It was fine yesterday, today it's not working

Comment: I tried with Follow path by parenting it to a bone, but It doesn't give me keyframes to slow down and speed up the animation.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd need the .blend file to help you further, can you share it?

Comment: I think I got this done, but this is not what I Want I guess.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9hBQFIf_OQ I need to make something like this, it doesn't have to be as great as that tho. If you have a tutorial I need to watch for it.